# Google Sheet join cells with text placement

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, transpose, flatten, google-query-language

Is it possible to have a formula in Google sheet to place the 1st text of the  2nd column next to 1st text of the first column, and the  2nd text of the  2nd column next to 2nd text of the first column

LIke :>

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| row1a row1b | text1a text1b |
| row2a row2b | text2a text2b |

into this:

| A header |
| --- |
| row1a text1a row1b text1b |
| row2a text2a row2b text2b |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(
 TRANSPOSE(A2:B),,9^9)), " "), "select Col1,Col3,Col2,Col4", )),,9^9))))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thank you and what if multiples rows are inside both cells but want to accomplish similar below?

Comment: @JLMasc then try just: `=FLATTEN(QUERY(
 TRANSPOSE(A2:B),,9^9))`  or `={A2:A&" "&B2:B}`

Comment: only the text1 and row2 sit next to each other

Comment: @player0 - Can you please explain the 9^9 parameter used as header in google query function, what does it do and how does it work?

Comment: @WesleyJeftha sure, 9^9 is just a big number with no further significance. it can be any big number you wish for like 12243504153 or 251245, 888^5, 100000, etc. it doesn't matter whats the value. the only rule is that it needs to be equal or higher than all rows in the sheet (if your sheet has 10 rows in total the number can be 11). in such manner, you can think of this parameter as "get all rows"